# ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number oracledb (python)

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle, python-oracledb

I want to insert data into my Oracle table, which has the following structure:

```
SUBJECT             VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)
TEXT                LONG
PREDICTED_CATEGORY  VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE)
TRUE_CATEGORY       VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE)
PROBABILITY         VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)
NUMBER_ANONYMIZED_TOKENS    VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE)
CASEID              VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE)
```

For this I have prepared row according to the documentation (https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-by-name-or-position)

```
data = {"subject": 'anon_subj', "txt": 'anon_text', "pred_cat": pred_class,"true_cat": "", "prob": str(probability),"num_anon": num_anon_tokens ,"caseid": str(caseID)}
```

I have prepared SQL Insert statement as well:

```
statement= "INSERT INTO MY_ORACLE_TABLE(SUBJECT, TEXT, PREDICTED_CATEGORY, TRUE_CATEGORY, PROBABILITY, NUMBER_ANONYMIZED_TOKENS, CASEID) VALUES (:subject, :txt, :pred_cat, :true_cat, :prob, :num_anon, :caseid)"
```

I have a executed the following code:

```
oracledb.init_oracle_client()
con = oracledb.connect(DB_CONNECTION_STRING, encoding='UTF-8', nencoding='UTF-8')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.bindarraysize = 1       
cur.execute(statement, data)
con.commit()
cur.close()
```

After Execution I get the error ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number oracledb (python), which is most definitely connected to my binding variables. I have looked up many posts on stackoverflow with the same question, but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Nothing is sticking out as wrong to me. Are the values for the variables `pred_class`, `probability`, `num_anon_tokens`, and `caseID` all reasonable and match your expectations?

Comment: @JNevill yes, basically I tested insert with an example above and I am getting this error. Every variable is a string, as expected in the table

Comment: I'm finding conflicting information on `bindarraysize`. I'm not sure why you're setting it, but what happens if you leave out that line?

Comment: @Barmar same error, nothing changed

Comment: does the same string work in the oracle DB ?

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake:

I just made a silly mistake in my function. My original function was:

```
oracledb.init_oracle_client()
        con = oracledb.connect(DB_CONNECTION_STRING, encoding='UTF-8', nencoding='UTF-8')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.bindarraysize = 1
        if ("_TABLE" in statement):
            cur.setinputsizes(t_date=oracledb.TIMESTAMP)
        cur.execute(statement, data)
        con.commit()
        cur.close()
```

Basically, the if statemnt was the reason of the error. I didn't pay attention to it because of fatigue, that's why I didn't copy it into my original post.

I am sorry for taking your time and thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad you got it resolved.  A side comment: remove the encoding and nencoding parameters as they do nothing and have just been removed from python-oracledb 2.0, i.e you will get an error if you try to use those long deprecated parameters.